# Web API mixed mode authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a web API which can be used using both HMAC and windows authentication. I have a working sample using HMAC but I'm not sure how to go about allowing users with windows authentication to also query the API.

Is it possible to support multiple authorization routes?
Any examples of an approach I could use to solve this would be appreciated.

Thanks!